# Creating An Association between 2 models In Express-Sequelize MySql

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Disclaimer: I am very new to

```
Node/Express/Sequelize
```

**Questions:**

**1.** Do I need to import visitors.js to visitorsInfo.js so that I can create an association between the 2?

**2.** If not, how do I set up the visitorsInfo_id as a Foreign Key from visitors.js column visitors_id?

Snippet:
...model/visitors.js

```
'use strict'

module.exports = ( sequelize , type ) => {
    return sequelize.define( 'visitors' , {
        visitor_id: {
            type: type.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        web_status: {
            type: type.BOOLEAN
        },
        digital_status: {
            type: type.BOOLEAN
        },
        hosting_status: {
            type: type.BOOLEAN
        },
        training_status: {
            type: type.BOOLEAN
        },
    })
}
```

.../model/visitors_info.js

```
'use strict'

module.exports = ( sequelize , type) => {
    return sequelize.define( 'user_info' , {
        visitorsInfo_id: {
            type: type.INTEGER,
            /* 
                How to set up foreign key...?
            */
        },
        firstname: {
            type: type.STRING
        },
        lastname: {
            type: type.STRING
        },
        company: {
            type: type.STRING
        },
        contact_info: {
            type: type.INTEGER
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No need import visitors.js to visitorsInfo.js
2. Base on the document from [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html), In file visitorsInfo.js

   ```
   'use strict'
   module.exports = ( sequelize , type) => {
   var user_info = sequelize.define( 'user_info' , {
       visitorsInfo_id: {
           type: type.INTEGER,
       },
       firstname: {
           type: type.STRING
       },
       lastname: {
           type: type.STRING
       },
       company: {
           type: type.STRING
       },
       contact_info: {
           type: type.INTEGER
       }
   });

      user_info.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        user_info.belongsTo(models.visitors, {
           as: 'visitors',
           foreignKey: 'visitorsInfo_id',
           targetKey: 'visitor_id'
        });
       }
       return user_info
   }
   ```